# Separation axioms and $G_\delta$ set

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space such that each singleton of $X$ is $G_\delta.$ Then  $(X,T)$ is $T_1$-space.

To see that, take $x,y\in X$ where $x\neq y.$ It is enough to show that there two sets say $U_x$ and $V_y$ such that $x\in U_x$ and $y\not\in U_x$ and $x\not\in V_y$ and $y\in V_y.$ Notice that $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are $G_\delta$ sets. So, $$\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} U_n  \,\, , \{y\}=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} V_n,$$  where $U_n$ and $V_n$ are open sets for all $n\in\Bbb N.$ Notic that there must be  $n_1,n_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in U_{n_1}$ and $y\not\in U_{n_1}$ and also $x\not\in V_{n_2}$  and $y\in V_{n_2}.$ Then, $(X, T)$ is $T_1$-space.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is right.

Note that in fact you're really using a much weaker hypothesis: that every singleton is *the intersection of some collection of open sets of arbitrary cardinality*. As soon as we know that $y\not\in \{x\}=\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i$, this tells us that there must be some $i\in I$ with $y\not\in U_i$ but $x\in U_i$.

In particular, note that once we drop the cardinality constraint on our collection of open sets, each point gets a "canonical candidate object" which lets us extract from the argument above the following sharper result:

> For a topological space $(X,\tau)$, the following are **equivalent**:
>
> - $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$.
> - For each $x\in X$ we have $$\bigcap_{x\in U\in\tau}U=\{x\}.$$

This is worth observing, even if it is in retrospect pretty tautological (think about what "$T_1$" is saying in the first place), since it suggests a family of *cardinality-based strengthenings* of $T_1$ness: given a (possibly finite!) cardinal $\kappa$, say that a space $\mathcal{X}$ is $T_1$-by-$\kappa$ iff every singleton in $\mathcal{X}$ is the intersection of a collection of open sets of size $<\kappa$. For example, "every singleton is $G_\delta$" corresponds to $T_1$-by-$\omega_1$-ness. This richer language doesn't have any immediate payoff yet, but $(i)$ will become relevant later on once you start considering cardinal functions on topological spaces and $(ii)$ may help demystify the role of $G_\delta$ness as a specific hypothesis in various arguments *(e.g. you'll be poised to reflexively ask "is $T_1$-by-$\omega_2$ enough?" and so forth)*.

*(Note that $T_1$-by-$\omega$ is a pretty boring property - since intersections of finitely many open sets are open, a space is $T_1$-by-$\omega$ iff it is discrete!)*

Comment: Noah Schweber, thank you for the nice explanation as usual.  Just to make sure did you mean by "what "$T_1$" is saying in the first place" this is actually a definition for $T_1$

Comment: The minimal cardinality of $I$ is called $\pi\chi(x,X)$, the pseudo-character of $x$. Also $\psi(x,X)$ in some papers.

Comment: Noah Schweber , Did you see my comment ?